# How can I easily Iterate NumPy arrays using approaches other than #nditer?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration, cython

I would like to Iterate each cell value of arrays. I tried it using np.nditer methods (for i in np.nditer(bar_st_1). However, even with 64 GB RAM laptop it tooks alot of computational time and runs out of memory. Do you know what will be the easiest and fastets way to extract each array values? Thanks

```
#Assign the crop specific irrigated area of each array for each month accoridng to the crop calander
#Barley
for Barley in df_dist.Crop:
    for i in np.nditer(bar_st_1):
        for j in df_area.Month:
            for k in df_dist.Planting_month:
                for l in df_dist.Maturity_month:
                    if (j>= min(k,l)) and (j<= max(k,l)):
                        df_area.Barley=i
                    else:
                        df_area.Barley=0
```

My goal is to extract a value of each array and assign it for each growing season (month). df_dist is a district-level data frame containing the growing area for each month. bar_st_1 is an array (7*7) that contains an irrigated area of a specific district. For each specific cell, I would like to extract the value of the corresponding array and assign it for a specific month based on the growing season (if the condition is stated above)

Comment: We'll need a little more information on what you're trying to do. What does `df_dist` look like? What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is to extract a value of each array and assign it for each growing season (month). df_dist is a district-level data frame containing the growing area for each month. bar_st_1 is an array (7*7) that contains an irrigated area of a specific district. For each specific cell, I would like to extract the value of the corresponding array and assign for a specific month based on the growing season (if the condition is stated above).

Comment: iterating over a numpy array will *always be relatively slow*. This is a very important thing to understand about numpy

Comment: More fundamentally, whatever you are doing here seems to be using a brute-force approach taking a cartesian product of various things, and this will scale very, very poorly in any language

Comment: Forget using `nditer`.  It doesn't help with speed, or memory.  If `bar_st_1` is (7,7) you could just as well use `for i in bar_st_1.ravel():`.  In other words, here `nditer` is just flat iterator through the elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for j in df_area.Month:
>            for k in df_dist.Planting_month:
>                for l in df_dist.Maturity_month:
>                    if (j>= min(k,l)) and (j<= max(k,l)):
>                        df_area.Barley=i
>                    else:
>                        df_area.Barley=0
> ```

This code block seems to be wasting a lot of effort. If you changed the order of the iterations, you could write

```
for k in df_dist.Planting_month:
   for l in df_dist.Maturity_month:
      for j in range(min(k,l), max(k,l)+1):
                        df_area.Barley=i
```

Then you avoid making a lot of comparisons and calculating a lot of max(k,l)'s that aren't necessary.

The loop over `i` is also wasting effort, since you write certain entries of `df_area.Barley` to `i`, but then in a later iteration you overwrite them with a different value of `i`, without ever (in the code you've shared) using `df_area` with the first value of `i`.

So you could reduce your code to

```
for Barley in df_dist.Crop:
   # Initialize the df_area array for this crop with zeros:
   df_area.Barley = np.zeros(df_area.Month.max())
   r, c = bar_st_1.shape
   # Choose the last element in bar_st_1:
   i = bar_st_1[r-1, c-1]
   for k in df_dist.Planting_month:
      for l in df_dist.Maturity_month:
         for j in range(min(k,l), max(k,l)+1):
                           df_area.Barley=i
```

Now you've eliminated one level from your nested loop structure and shortened the iteration in another level, so you're likely to get 10x or better improvement in speed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed comments. I genuinely appreciate your help.